# Neuroph: Error at Neural network learning

Tags: neural-network

I´m trying to run an Artificial Neural Network with Neuroph Studio, using the given example of a Multi Layer Perceptron Network. Every time I try, I get the same error in the log console:

```
SEVERE [global]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.neuroph.core.learning.SupervisedLearning.beforeEpoch(SupervisedLearning.java:127)
    at org.neuroph.core.learning.IterativeLearning.learn(IterativeLearning.java:163)
[catch] at org.neuroph.core.NeuralNetwork$1.run(NeuralNetwork.java:289)
```

My system is:

```
Product Version: NeurophStudio 201210100934
Java: 1.7.0_07; Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 23.3-b01
System: Windows 7 version 6.1 running on amd64; Cp1252; es_ES (neurophstudio)
User directory: C:\Users\i3casa\AppData\Roaming\.neurophstudio\dev
Cache directory: C:\Users\i3casa\AppData\Roaming\.neurophstudio\dev\var\cache
```

Do you know any ammendment to this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for this question was that I had to open the training set in the Neuroph Studio before training the network. Otherwise, no training set was found, and a Null poiner exception was launched.